# to search for numeric or alphanumeric strings before or after some keywords in java

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

How to find numeric or alphanumeric strings before or after some keywords in a string in java using stanford corenlp.

**Situation:** I need to extract codes which are a string containing only `digits` or `digits+alphabets` or `digits + special characters` like `'*'` or `'#'` from sentences containing some predefined keywords.The codes can be anywhere before or after the keywords.

I am a beginner in NLP and need help on this.

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! Can you please provide some research and/or other details on what your question to help others answer it better?

Comment: for ex- To enter the building the password for the gate is 1234A.               There will be many sentences like this and i need to extract 1234A. In this example my keywords can be "password" and "gate" and "enter". I want to do this using stanford corenlp tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
(?<=(keyword1|keyword2))\\s+([a-zA-Z0-9*#]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9*#]+)\\s+(?=(keyword1|keyword2))
```